# MongoDB change stream replica set recovery

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I implemented MongoDB change streams with Spring and it works fine when the replica set primary node is up.

```
@Service
public class ChangeEventService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeEventService.class);
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    public ChangeEventService(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void subscribe() {
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("experiment");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("debug");
        Block<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> printBlock = changeStreamDocument -> {
            logger.info("Received: {}", changeStreamDocument.getFullDocument().toString());
            BsonDocument resumeToken = changeStreamDocument.getResumeToken();
        };
        collection.watch().forEach(printBlock);
        logger.info("Consumer is ready to process");
    }
}
```

Then I shut down the primary node of the replica set. I was expecting the change stream to wait for the replica set to elect a new primary and continue to get the data changes. The actual behavior is an application crash.

From the logs I can see that the connection to the primary (27000) is closed which is expected, then it seems to try to open a connection to one of the secondary (27001) but can't because the pool has been closed.

From the documentation: "The change stream is bound to a collection and change stream documents are iterated with a cursor. This cursor remains open until it is explicitly closed, as long as a connection to the MongoDB deployment remains open and the collection exists."

```
2018-05-02 12:03:03.424  INFO 9560 --- [           main] c.e.m.service.ChangeEventService         : Received: Document{{_id=5ae98cd7dcc8921c94d5f9e5, _class=com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, uuid=4f836d00-efc3-4d48-956a-af4dbfed90e7, now=Wed May 02 12:03:03 CEST 2018}}
2018-05-02 12:03:06.500  WARN 9560 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Got socket exception on connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:8}] to localhost:27000. All connections to localhost:27000 will be closed.
2018-05-02 12:03:06.501  INFO 9560 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:8}] to localhost:27000 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
2018-05-02 12:03:07.502  INFO 9560 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:6}] to localhost:27000 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
2018-05-02 12:03:07.504  WARN 9560 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'changeEventService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
2018-05-02 12:03:07.505  INFO 9560 --- [localhost:27000] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27000
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
2018-05-02 12:03:07.507  INFO 9560 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:181}] to localhost:27001
2018-05-02 12:03:07.508  INFO 9560 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:181}] to localhost:27001 because the pool has been closed.
2018-05-02 12:03:07.511  INFO 9560 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2
```

Comment: Quick question. If you try another listing and put a tailable cursor directly  on the oplog then what happens? I'm kind of expecting the same thing as I'm expecting that to be the core place where what you are expecting to be checked for simply does not happen "in the driver". My gut says you need to trap the exceptions and resume the stream yourself, but if it actually works with a base tailable cursor, then that core code is in the driver somewhere and I'd be willing to call "bug" at that point. But NOT before, as I suspect this is intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here:

> at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]

There is a bug with [MongoDB Java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) v3.6.3, where [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) cursor does not resume when there's an attempt to kill the existing cursor fails. This is described in [JAVA-2821](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2821), and fixed in version 3.7.0 onwards.

> collection.watch().forEach(printBlock);

The `watch()` method does't actually contact the server, instead you should use an iterator method. For example:

```
MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor = collection.watch().iterator();

ChangeStreamDocument<Document> next = cursor.next();

while(cursor.hasNext()){
    next = cursor.next();
    System.out.println(next);
}
```

See also [Spec: Resumable Error](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/change-streams.rst#resumable-error) for the definition of error that is considered resumable.

Comment: I tested with version 3.7.0-rc0 and it works fine using my original code